# Hyperlink base on another column

Tags: hyperlink, google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery. Is there a way to Hyperlink base on another column's info?

In other words, how to hyperlink a specific column based on a specific ID (in another column) in the same table? E.g. How to create a hyperlink column "Program" by referencing the "SF_Record_ID" ID

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PMD_PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%MANO%' THEN 'Brazil MAO' 
WHEN PC.COUNTRY ='BR' THEN 'Brazil'
ELSE GEO.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION
END AS Country  
, IFNULL(PMD.PMD_FRANCHISE,"Unspecified") as Franchise
, PC.PMD_PROGRAM_NAME AS Progam 
, PC.PMD_PRODUCT_NAME AS Product
, PC.KEY_CUSTOMER AS Key_Customer
, PC.PRODUCT_STATUS AS Product_Status 
, PC.SF_RECORD_ID AS SF_Record_ID
, PC.PRODUCT_COST AS Cost


SF_Record_ID is the unique ID
Link: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SF_Record_ID/view"
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your question is about and provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for assisting,
My goal is to have the Program column transform into a hyperlink (referencing the SF_Record_ID) inside the table.

Comment: read my comment again please!  you should provide sample of input data and desired output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to achieve this:

```
DECLARE HLINK_PREFIX STRING;
DECLARE HLINK_POSTFIX STRING;
SET HLINK_PREFIX = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/";
SET HLINK_POSTFIX = "/view";
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""SELECT concat(concat('%t', SF_Record_ID),'%t') FROM table""",HLINK_PREFIX,HLINK_POSTFIX);
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting.

I'm very new to bigquery and How do you insert this "DECLARE" to make the column Program turn into a hyperlink of SF_Record_ID

Comment: You can use INSERT statement to add hyperlink values to a target table. Example: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""INSERT INTO target_table SELECT SF_Record_ID, concat(concat('%t', SF_Record_ID),'%t') FROM source_table""",HLINK_PREFIX,HLINK_POSTFIX);`